# Laying out images as a dealt deck of cards

Tags: java, android-studio, layout

I want to display my images on the screen so that they look like 4 hands of a card game dealt out, a group to the top of the screen, a group to the bottom, a group to the left and a group to the right. I have the following code that displays them at the top and bottom but how do I get the ones to show on the right and left without my tops and bottoms being pushed off the screen? Should I change my layout to a grid layout? I am using Android Studio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".layoutdeck">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_card_top1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/aback" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_top2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_top3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_top4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_top5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_top6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_top7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_top8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_top9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_top10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_top11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_top12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_top13"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/aback" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_top14"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_top15"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="655dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom13"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom14"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom15"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/aback" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom14"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="661dp"

        android:layout_marginRight="661dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:foregroundGravity="right"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/aback" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_card_bottom14"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginEnd="711dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="711dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="336dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/aback" />




></LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FitToWindows = True in the base layout and try placing the group of cards relative to each other. This will bound the group of cards to each other.

I hope it works